# VBA to apply style to all images in Word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word

Is it possible to apply a style or at least give a thin border to all the images in a Word 2013 document using VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work,

```
Dim pic As InlineShape
For Each pic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
  pic.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
  pic.Borders.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, Jimmy Smith. There are also arrows and boxes (regular shapes created in Word). Will this code apply a border to those as well or just the images inserted into the document from an external source?

Comment: It shouldn't, per Microsoft an inline shape can only be a picture, an OLE object, or an ActiveX control.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221989(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply a style to the images use this macro:

```
Sub set_image_to_figure_style()
  Dim pic As InlineShape
  For Each pic In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    pic.Select
    Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Figure")
  Next
End Sub
```